# How to create a product in flipkart using seller listing apis?

Tags: flipkart-api

I want to sync product my ecommerce site with flipkart so how to create product in flipkart using seller listing apis

Comment: Did you refer to the page at https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/listing-api-docs/LMAPIRef.html

Comment: yes but there is a product id for listing product i don't know that id

Comment: Looks like you need to create the product id on your side. Would request you to update the question with the exact issue(s) that you're facing